# How to merge tapply() functions in R?

Tags: r, dataset, tapply

Input:

```
data(iris)
tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, mean)
tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, median)
```

Desired output: A dataset that shows the following

```
#setosa versicolor virginica
#5.006  5.936      6.588
#5.0    5.9        6.5
```

What is the best way to create a new, single dataset that includes the various tapply() outputs?

Comment: `aggregate(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris, function(x) c(mean(x), median(x)))`? Or just use `dplyr`/`data.table` such as `data.table(iris)[, .(mean(Sepal.Length), median(Sepal.Length)), by = Species]` or  `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(mean(Sepal.Length), median(Sepal.Length))`

Comment: another one `t(sapply(list(mean, median), function(x) with(iris, tapply(Sepal.Length, Species, x))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like so:

```
data(iris)
x <- tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, mean)
y <- tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, median)
df <- rbind(x, y)
df
```

It yields

```
  setosa versicolor virginica
x  5.006      5.936     6.588
y  5.000      5.900     6.500
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this with one `tapply` call:

```
mat <-
do.call(cbind, 
        tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, function(x) c(mean(x), median(x)))
        )
```

Output:

```
> mat
     setosa versicolor virginica
[1,]  5.006      5.936     6.588
[2,]  5.000      5.900     6.500
```

Comment: You got the shaft on that one.  This is the better answer

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven. That's ok, whatever works for the OP, I don't mind. And in all fairness you were faster than me with your answer by 1 second :P. I tried to upvote but got an error because you deleted yours.

Comment: I think this is the better answer too :-)